# Improve StackExchange UX

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I have a number of usability issues with SE and have addressed some on MSO. I'm wondering if these questions should be better addressed here (migrated) than at MSO as they are very specific UX oriented.

You can look at [my profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/164044/gui-junkie) and see for yourselves.

- Top notification bar (I'm against it, but would welcome a second opinion).
- Feedback to users (not posted yet).
- Clickonomics.
- Auto-login vs create user (not posted yet).

The way I see it, SE could use some professional advise, and the crowd at UX seems very knowledgeable (far more than I am).

The question is whether MSO should be the only place to discuss UX issues with SE.

Comment: MSO was created as the place to go to if you have a problem with the way the network of sites works. UX's meta is for issues specific to our stack. However, most UX people are here. So there's definitely a case to be made for asking the question in either location.

Comment: @Rahul. Problems with the entire network can be posted on any site's meta, because some people are members of only one site. Posts tagged `bug` on any meta site will be read by the developers.